# Can one single Corda node support multiple parties/accounts?

Tags: corda

Just wonder if a single Corda node can support multiple accounts like Bitcoin does.

A related open question I found on discourse https://discourse.corda.net/t/can-you-have-a-corda-identity-adress-without-running-a-node/1298

From Peter FroystadFroystadP6d

Does Corda support multiple people having accounts/addresses on the network without running a Corda node?
Similar to how Bitcoin allow people to own coins with a private key, but not running a full node?

In the financial world, this would correspond to people having an account in the bank, and they would share facts on a 1-1 basis with their bank regarding their dealings. These customers wouldn't run a peer node however. But they would want a service similar to a Bitcoin wallet that would allow them to access their dealings with the bank

Answer (score 7):

Corda is designed for varied institutions which are not all banks, so it doesn't have a direct concept of "account" like Bitcoin does. If you want to implement customer accounts on top of Corda you need to track the balances yourself and use Corda for inter-institutional transfers. Corda's ability to easily integrate with SQL databases and MQ makes that kind of integration quite easy though.

If you're asking about multiple *identities* on a single node, so one machine can do both legal entity A and B at once, the answer is: we're working on it.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your answer and advice. Yes I'm thinking about bank/exchange use cases for its clients. Very encouraging to know R3 are working on it. Cheers.

Comment: As of Corda 3.2, multiple identities on a node is not yet supported. However, cordite.foundation is a CorDapp currently in alpha that implements the ability to assign tokens to accounts.

Comment: hi mike, any idea when multiple identities within a corda node will be made available? In many settings, it is not practical to run a full node for every peer.

Comment: Mike, is it possible yet to have multiple accounts on a single node? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible with Corda 4.3 and the new Accounts SDK

https://github.com/corda/accounts

However, it is not a simple drop in replacement for `Party` and requires changes to an existing cordapp and implementing several parts of the business logic of what you might consider an "account" or "wallet".

Answer (score 1):

According to the blog post by Mike Hearn: https://discourse.corda.net/t/mobile-consumer-payment-experiences-with-corda-on-ledger-cash/966

> Note that your balance in this scheme is simply your bank balance. There are no separate wallets.

It looks to me running multiple accounts/parties on a single node is not supported in the moment. Yet, we may expect the support realized in Phase 2 Bitcoin SPV wallet mode.

> In phase two this is extended to support a model more like Bitcoin SPV, whereby the sending device manages its own private keys and transaction data. It thus becomes a true wallet app.

Comment: we have a similar use case. Any changes in Corda 4 for this. I have gone through the documentation, but doesn't seem feasible