# Corda API for signing and generating certificate for Customer's identity data (not node user)

Tags: corda

Corda provides ability to generate node's private key and public key by using doorman service, and signed data while executing transaction.

Is there any API through which i can sign customer's identity and store this identity in node's database.

For example: In KYC usecase, if Bank is participating in consortium and adding customer demographic details, is there any provision in Corda in which i can generate customer's identity(in form of certificate and private key) and store it in Bank's node database.

This identity will become blockchain identity for Customer, through which it can share same customer's KYC details with another bank(another participant)

Answer (score 0):

The doorman doesn't generate the node's public/private key. The keys are generated on the node side. The node then keeps the private key secret, but provides the public key to the doorman for inclusion in its certificate (see [Sequence of steps when a Corda node starts up and joins a network for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832752/sequence-of-steps-when-a-corda-node-starts-up-and-joins-a-network-for-the-first) for the sequence of steps involved).

The node also doesn't current support multiple identities. It's currently one identity per node. See [Can one single Corda node support multiple parties/accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020131/can-one-single-corda-node-support-multiple-parties-accounts).

You *could* however represent the customer's information as a state, and sign this state using the node's key.