# What sequence of steps does a Corda node perform when it starts up and joins a network for the first time?

Tags: corda

What is the sequence of steps that a Corda node performs when it starts up for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Corda 3, upon first starting up, the node goes through four steps:

## 1. Obtains the network root certificate out-of-band and stores it in the node's folder under `certificates/network-root-truststore.jks`

- This location can be overidden using the `--network-root-truststore` flag
- If using a doorman, this root certificate will be used to validate the certificates they provide to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks

## 2. Sets up the nodes certificates

You have two options here:

- 2a: Run the node against a doorman by starting the node with the flags `--initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password <trust store password>` (see `NodeStartup.registerWithNetwork`):

  - Create a new node keystore
  - Make a certificate request to the certificate signing service
  - Poll and download its certificate and associated certificate chain from the certificate signing service
  - Check the certificate chain against the root CA cert obtained out-of-band
  - Store the certificate chain and private key in its node keystore
  - Create a truststore
  - Save the root certificate in its truststore
  - Create an SSL keystore
  - Generate an SSL keypair and certificate
  - Store its SSL private key and certificate in its SSL keystore
- 2b: Provision the certificates yourself

In either case, your certificates will have to meet the requirements set out in the [permissioning docs](https://docs.corda.net/head/permissioning.html). You can use [`X509Utilities`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/crypto/X509Utilities.kt) to create the certs. See [`X509UtilitiesTest.kt`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node-api/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/crypto/X509UtilitiesTest.kt) for an example.

## 3. Uploads its info to the network map (see `AbstractNode.updateNodeInfo`)

- The node generates its own signed node info file
- The node uploads its own `nodeInfo` to the network map

## 4. Polls the network for the network's parameters and other nodes (see `NetworkMapUpdater.subscribeToNetworkMap`):

- The node downloads the network parameters
- The node downloads the network map
- For each `nodeInfo` hash in the network map, the node downloads the corresponding `nodeInfo` and add it to the node's local cache

Comment: Can single corda node register on with 2 different doorman service? How single corda node part of multiple corda networks?